# How to create C# windows service app to run on multiple servers targeting a single folder checking for new files

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to run an C# window service app on multiple servers to check a single folder for new files, if files found then process them or move them. Now if ServerA is processing the file, ServerB, ServerC should not process the same file.

I have created the app running on a single server but do not know how to achieve multi machine scenario.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

I usually just have a separat folder named something like "Processing". As soon as I identify what file to process, I move the file to the processing folder. That way, multiple treads accessing the primary folder, is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am doing it already. I am concerned about the time if 2 servers try to access that folder at a same time. Just as an precaution.

Comment: Well, all but one of them will get something like a "File not found" exception when trying to move/process the file. One of them will have the valid handle, all others will get nothing.